# Unable to Compile Contract in Brownie (not receiving a .json file in "build" folder )

Tags: go-ethereum, brownie

I'm currently running Brownie in Studio Visual Code. My problem is that when I write a smart contract and try to compile it using command "Brownie Compile" I don't' receive a .json file in the "build" folder afterwards. I receive a message that says:

"INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.14.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at C:\Users\Brian Lee.brownie\New folder\build\contracts"

It says project has been compiled but I don't see the .json file anywhere. Do you have any suggestions? I think I may have set up my folders incorrectly. I'm new to coding in general so I'm experiencing a lot of confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed solidity dependencies. You must install a solidity compiler and visual studio 2019 to sort this out. Follow this guidance https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/installing-solidity.html#versioning

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the obvious, make sure you have saved the .sol file. I had the same issue, and realized that the .sol file with the contract code hadn't been saved only when looking at the contents of the directory and noticing the file was 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

you should move the *.sol contract file to the contract folder. Brownie only compiles files present in this folder .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Solidity contract file in the `contracts` folder and brownie says it has compiled without any error but nothing shows up in the `build/contracts` folder:

- Confirm that the filename extension is all lower-case `.sol`

I had mistyped my file's extension to be `.Sol` and that threw brownie off.  As soon as I made the capital 'S' lower-case, brownie compiled successfully and wrote the correct output to the `build/contracts` folder.